A strange identity between generalized basic hypergeometric series
Calculating matrix elements in some quantum integrable system, I encountered a strange $q$-series identity for non-terminating basic hypergeometric functions $\phantom{i}_3\phi_2$. It comes from the symmetry of the problem with respect to the permutation of two parameters. The final answer is not symmetric and this results in the following identity
\begin{align}
&\left(1-\frac{qab}{cd}\right)\phantom{i}_3\phi_2\left(\begin{array}{c}a, b, q\nonumber\\ c,  d  \end{array};q,q\right)-
\left(1-\frac{q}{d}\right)\phantom{i}_3\phi_2\left(\begin{array}{c}{\displaystyle\frac{c}{a}, \frac{c}{b}}, q\\
 c,  {\displaystyle\frac{cd}{ab}}  \end{array};q,q\right)=\\
&=\Pi_1(a,b,c,d)\phantom{i}_2\phi_1\left(\begin{array}{c}{\displaystyle{qa}/{b}, {qb}/{d}}\nonumber\\ {\displaystyle{qc}/{d}} \end{array};q,q\right)+\Pi_2(a,b,c,d)\phantom{i}_2\phi_1\left(\begin{array}{c}{\displaystyle{qa}/{b}, {qb}/{d}}\nonumber\\ {\displaystyle{qab}/{d}} \end{array};q,q\right),
\end{align}
where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary parameters and $\Pi_{1,2}(a,b,c,d)$ are some products of $q$-Pochhammer symbols. This formula connects two non-balanced series $\phantom{i}_3\phi_2$ with the argument $z=q$ and one of the top parameters is also equal to $q$.
It has been checked numerically and it works.
All series are non-terminating, so the only formula I could find for such series is (III.34) from Appendix III in the Gasper-Rahman book. Obviously, (III.34) can not be applied here. I consider myself as a good expert in basic hypergeometric functions and I have never seen such identity before. I would greatly appreciate any hint how to prove it.

I don't know anything about q-hypergeometric series, but does this reduce to a known identity for ordinary HGM series for $q=1$ ?

Expanding as formal power series in $q$ and comparing constant terms gives $\Pi_1(a,b,c,d) = -\Pi_2(a,b,c,d)$. I don't think you're complicating things unnecessarily, so this makes me wonder whether there's a typo or a missing term.
